# Call to a member function on null - retrieving data from a many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

This question is pretty common, but I couldn't figure it out how to do it in my case.

Here's the code:

```
public function index($id)
    {
        $student = Student::with('referat')->with('examen')->findOrFail($id);
        $materii = Materie::find(1)->domeniu()->where('id_domeniu', $student->domeniu_doctorat_id)->pluck('id_domeniu');
        dd($materii);

        return view('admin.students.catalog.index')->with([
            'student' => $student
        ]);
    }
```

The $id that I use in the index function is the user id.
Now I want to retrieve all the materii (materii = subjects) which are linked to their fields (domeniu = field).

For example, the subject Math is in the Science domain. Subjects (materii) and domenii (fields) are stored in a many-to-many intermediate table, which can be accessed with the function domeniu()

Materii model

```
public function domeniu()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DomeniuDoctorat::class, 'materie_domeniu', 'id_materie', 'id_domeniu');
    }
```

In the code above you can see my approach - but I get "call to a member function domeniu() on null", because the find doesn't work as I want.

My idea was to get all the subjects (materii) with that find, then go to the intermediate table with domeniu(), and then find the subjects which the student is interested in, by checking the field they like (domeniu).

But because find doesn't work as I expect, this doesn't work.

Is my idea alright? If so, how should the find look in order for my code work?

Photo with error message:
[image: click]

Many to many table migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMaterieDomeniu extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('materie_domeniu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_materie');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_domeniu');
            $table->foreign('id_materie')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('materii')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('id_domeniu')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('domenii_doctorat')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('materie_domeniu');
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that `Materie::find(1)` will always find the model with the ID 1, rather than returning 1 model. To do that, you'd need to do something like `limit` or `take`, depending on whether you are in query builder.

Comment: @JustCarty no, I didn't know that to be honest. isn't there anything like findAll()? Or what would be the best way to do what I want to?

Comment: Can y7ou include the exact error message with stacktrace

Comment: @mrhn I added a photo.

Comment: @mrhn I also added the many to many table, just in case.

Comment: Pretty straight forward materii::find(1) does not exist :)

Comment: @mrhn Yes, I figured that out already :) but how can I fix that? I said that I wanted to retrieve all the objects with that, but it doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but i'm not certain that i completely understand. It's your table, you have the models, you must know which row to fetch out?

Comment: @mrhn I will try to explain it more coherently. Each student has a domeniu (field) that they like. Each domeniu (field) consists of multiple materii (subjects of study). I have a many-to-many field which stores what are the materii (subjects) of each domeniu (field). I need to retrieve the materii (subjects of study) of a student with a given id. Technically, that means to find all the id_materie from the many-to-many table where the id_domeniu is equal to the student's domeniu_doctorat_id .

Comment: But you have hardcoded the material, where should you get that id from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232040/discussion-between-octavian-niculescu-and-mrhn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply fetch all `Materii` from a `Student` by using the relationships.

```
$materii = $student->domeniu->materiiLegate;
```

Comment: This will only work for the first row. I need to make it work for all of them. I added a comment with a better explanation.